# Are constant C expressions evaluated at compile time or at runtime?

Tags: c, optimization, compiler-construction, standards, c-preprocessor

If I write a *#define* that performs an operation using other preprocessor constants, is the final value computed each time the macro appears at runtime? Does this depend on optimizations in the compiler, or is it covered under a standard?

Example:

```
#define EXTERNAL_CLOCK_FREQUENCY    32768
#define TIMER_1_S                   EXTERNAL_CLOCK_FREQUENCY
#define TIMER_100_MS                TIMERB_1_S / 10
```

Will the operation *32768 / 10* occur at runtime every time I use the TIMER_100_MS macro?

I would like to avoid the following:

```
#define EXTERNAL_CLOCK_FREQUENCY    32768
#define TIMER_1_S                   EXTERNAL_CLOCK_FREQUENCY
#define TIMER_100_MS                3276
```

---

#### Summary

A compiler is required to be able to evaluate constant integral expressions because they are necessary for calculating things like array sizes at compile time. However, the standard only says they "can" -- not "must" -- do so. Therefore, only a brain-dead compiler would not evaluate a constant integral expressions at compile time, but a simple check of the assembly output for an unconventional compiler would verify each case.

Comment: note that `TIMERB_1_S / 10` is `3276`, not `3277`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Macros are simply textual substitution, so in your example writing `TIMER_100_MS` in a program is a fancy way of writing `32768 / 10`.

Therefore, the question is when the compiler would evaluate `32768 / 10`, which is a constant integral expression.  I don't think the standard requires any particular behavior here (since run-time and compile-time evaluation is indistinguishable in effect), but any halfway decent compiler will evaluate it at compile time.

Comment: This is the key point. The preprocessor manipulates text, then the compiler gets it and knows _nothing_ about how much preprocessing has gone before...

Comment: Even if the preprocessor would do so, it can't do so as long it isn't defined this way: `#define TIMER_100_MS (TIMERB_1_S / 10)` Since you don't paranthese the expression, It would be wring to evaluate it to `3277` where you might have written `1 / TIMER_100_MS` (Where the result anyway wouldn't be what is wanted I guess) But if the preprocessor had evaluated the statement here allready the it would even break the operator priority order.

Answer (score 29):

Most answers in here focused on the effect of the macro substitution. But i think he wanted to know whether

```
32768 / 10
```

is evaluated at compile time. First of all, that is an arithmetic constant expression, and in addition a integral constant expression (because it has only got literals of integer type). The implementation is free to calculate it at runtime, but it must also be able to calculate it at compile time, because

1. it must give a diagnostic message if a constant expression is not representable in the type that its expression has
2. such expressions are allowed in contexts that require the value at translation time, for example if used as the size of an array dimension.

If the compiler can principally calculate the result already at compile time, it should use that value, and not recalculate it at runtime i think. But maybe there is some reason still to do that. I wouldn't know.

**Edit**: I'm sorry i've answered the question as if it were about C++. Noticed today you asked about C. Overflowing in an expression is deemed as undefined behavior in C, regardless of whether it happens in a constant expression or not. The second point is also true in C, of course.

**Edit**: As a comment notes, if the macro is substituted into an expression like `3 * TIMER_100_MS`, then this would evaluate `(3 * 32768) / 10`. Therefore, the simple and direct answer is *"No, it would not occur at runtime every time, because the division may not occur at all because of precedence and associativity rules"*. My answer above assumes that the macro is always substituted such that the division actually happens.

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is wrong. Because of the macro substitution, you cannot know what this evaluates to since it matters what appears next to it after the substitution.  For example, `3 * 32768 / 10` may be different than `32768 / 10 * 3` in an integer expression due to order of operations going left to right.  If the macro definition surrounded the expression with `()`, then the answer would be true.

Comment: @Brick but in that case it is not an "operation 32768 / 10". The question however was about the "operation 32768 / 10" only. So my answer says nothing about the "3 * 32768 / 10" case because it is "(3 * 32768) / 10". My answer is true about "32768 / 10 * 3" and the other cases where there is such an operation.

Comment: This is the question, copied directly: "Will the operation 32768 / 10 occur at runtime every time I use the TIMER_100_MS macro?" It's definitely about the use of the macro, and the macro evaluates without the parenthesis. You cannot know if this simplifies or not unless you know every place that the macro is used.

Answer (score 14):

I'm not aware of any standard that guarantees it will be optimized out. The preprocessor will substitute 32768/10 for TIMER_100_MS, which you can see by running gcc -c. To see whether the compiler is optimizing further, run gcc -S and check out the assembler. With gcc 4.1, even without any optimization flags, this gets reduced to the constant during compilation:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define EXTERNAL_CLOCK_FREQUENCY    32768
#define TIMER_1_S                   EXTERNAL_CLOCK_FREQUENCY
#define TIMER_100_MS                TIMER_1_S / 10

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  printf("%d\n", TIMER_100_MS);

  return(0);
}

gcc -S test.c
cat test.s

...
    popl    %ebx
    movl    $3276, 4(%esp)
    leal    LC0-"L00000000001$pb"(%ebx), %eax
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    call    L_printf$stub
...
```

Comment: Using this technique, you can show that even complicated math operations, like `log(3.0)` will get translated into inline immediate values, although the disassembly will encode `log(3.0)` as `4607626529066517259` which is the 64-bit integer cast of the equivalent IEEE double...

Answer (score 13):

From the [WG14/N1124 Committee Draft — May 6, 2005 ISO/IEC 9899:TC2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf):

> ### 6.6 Constant expressions
>
> #### Syntax
>
> constant-expression:
>       conditional-expression
>
> #### Description
>
> A constant expression can be
>   evaluated during translation rather
>   than runtime, and     accordingly may
>   be used in any place that a constant
>   may be.
>
> #### Constraints
>
> Constant expressions shall not
>   contain assignment, increment,
>   decrement, function-call, or comma
>   operators, except when they are
>   contained within a subexpression that
>   is not     evaluated.96)
>
> Each constant expression shall
>   evaluate to a constant that is in the
>   range of epresentable values for its
>   type.

Comment: Thanks for citing your source, it's a valuable resource.

Answer (score 11):

The compiler should optimize that expression out. I don't think it's requited to by the standard, but I've never seen a compiler that would NOT perform that task.

However, you should NOT write:

```
#define TIMER_100_MS      TIMERB_1_S / 10
```

... because that's a bug waiting to happen. You should always parenthesize #defines involving expressions.

```
#define TIMER_100_MS      (TIMERB_1_S / 10)
```

Consider :

```
i = 10 * TIMER_100_MS;
```

The first case would give 32768 ((10 * TIMERB_1_S) / 10) , the second 32760 (10 * (TIMERB_1_S / 10)). Not a critical difference here, but you MUST be aware of it!

Comment: Very good point and it's actually a critical difference: You might want to do x % TIMER_100_MS, and without parenthesis this will first take mod of x by TIMERB_1_S and then divide the result by 10. Had such a bug before when implementing a circular buffer :)

Answer (score 9):

> Will the operation 32768 / 10 occur at runtime every time I use the *TIMERB_100_MS* macro?

Every place in your code where you use `TIMERB_100_MS`, it will be replaced with `32768 / 10` by the preprocessor.

Whether that expression gets further optimized (it evaluates to a constant) is up to your compiler.

Answer (score 9):

Folks, this transformation is called "constant folding" and even most student compilers do it.  As long as you have a compiler built by somebody not you or your college roommate and you're compiling a statically typed language, you can count on it even without optimization turned on.  It's a different matter if you're dealing with some wacky dynamic language that is allowed to change the meaning of `/`.

Comment: Constant Folding! that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It`s incorrect, compilers can not manipulate floating point numbers at compile time. If you are satisfied with 3276 value at compile time then you are good to go, but there is no way compiler going to evaluate this at compile time with floating point precision. Floating points are too tricky for compilers to optimize, because optimizing a floating point number can lead to unexpected results in mathematical expressions, so a decent compiler (any gcc version, any clang version, any msvc version, any icc version) wont simplify it to 3276.8 , end of story.

And the other part of your question, you asked will it is going to be evaluated for each macro expansion. Again if you are fine with 3276 value then the answer is no, it depends from compiler, optimization level and the background, it can be placed in constant table or it can be inlined in code. Ever way you wont compute the same expression in runtime for each macro expansion. Again, if you want floating point precision to get 3276.8, than that expression will be evaluated for each macro expansion in run time.

Take a look here for more compilation and optimization aspects:
http://www.agner.org/optimize/#manuals

Comment: The result of integer division is well-defined. Where does floating-point math come into play?

Answer (score -4):

At compile time. This is a language standard (and always have been) and independent on the compiler.

**Edit**

A commenter asked for a reference -
quoting from "The C programming language" 2nd edition Appendix A12.3 (p. 229):

> A control line of the form
>
> ```
> #define identifier token-sequence
> ```
>
> causes the preprocessor to replace
>   subsequent instances of the identifier
>   with the given sequence of tokens;
>   leading and trailing whitespace around
>   the roken sequence is discaded

**End of edit**

Comment: I'm totally confused now. You post a reply which contradicts this (says they "can" be evaluated at translation time, not they "must" be.

Comment: @David: the macro will be EXPANDED at compile time (how else could it be), but there is no *guarantee* that the expression "TIMERB_1_S / 10" (ie the division) is not evaluated at runtime.

Comment: I don't see how that is relevant. If that answers the question that was being asked, the question needs to be rewritten.