# C Compiler Optimization - Macros Involving Arithmetic

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, c-preprocessor

I am debating an optimization issue with a friend, and need some assistance tracking down both the answer to this problem, and hopefully some official documentation I could read further.

I am told that when compiling a simple program in a production build setting (ie: `CCOPTS+=-O4`, no debug, etc), that the following code:

```
#define COEFFICIENT_F  (5.0f)
...
...
float f = 1.0f / COEFFICIENT_F;
```

...will be automatically optimized to something like so:

```
#define COEFFICIENT_F  (5.0f)
...
...
#define INV_COEFFICIENT_F (0.2f)
float f = 1.0f * INV_COEFFICIENT_F;
```

While, if I'm compiling for a debug build (ie: `CCOPTS+=-O0 DEBUG=-g`), the code will not optimize such an operation at the pre-processor level.

So, my question is twofold:

1. Does the optimization level passed to the compiler affect decisions made by the pre-processor?
2. Will GCC, for example, automatically perform such conversions, including pre-calculating the inverse coefficient at pre-processing time, and storing it in the data segment of my code, along with multiplying instead of dividing by its reciprocal?

Thank you!

Comment: Look at the assembler output of the two and compare?  fdiv vs fmul (or whatever your system's float op-codes are) will show the way.  I cannot answer your two questions directly though...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are constant C expressions evaluated at compile time or at runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436300/are-constant-c-expressions-evaluated-at-compile-time-or-at-runtime)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your answers are:

1. No. Pre-processing is performed as defined in the standard and is not affected by any optimization level.
2. The optimization you are referring to is not performed at pre-processing time, but during the long road from the front-end to the code generator.

Comment: I don't even believe that 2 is an optimization.  The compiler will see `1.0 / 5.0` and this will evaluate to `0.2` regardless of optimizer setting.

Comment: @trojanfoe That optimization is called _constant folding_, admittedly not a very advanced optimization, but nevertheless. Some front-ends (after pre-processing) may perform such optimization, but I judge that bad practice. Ah, so yes it may be peformed at -O0.

Comment: But does this change with optimizer setting?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the exact usage and exact circumstances of the compiler. In the exact example you are giving, it would have to be pretty silly compiler to not figure out that `1.0f/5.0f = 0.2f`, just like `1.0f*0.2f = 0.2f` (ok, in both cases, the result is probably `0.1999996` or soemthing similar.

Now, if, instead, we have some data that the compiler can't figure out during the compilation itself:

```
 float f[] = { 3.1415926f, 1.0f, 9.82f, 1.4142f };
 float res[4]; 

 for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    res[i] = f[i] / COEFFICIENT_F;
```

vs.

```
 for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    res[i] = f[i] * INV_COEFFICIENT_F;
```

it may give some difference (particularly in lower optimization levels, since the optimizer will not replace trivial math operations with other math operations until you get to at least -O2).

How much of a difference this makes depends on the processor architecture.

To figure out the exact difference, you would have to write up a small program and measure it. (doing a larger number than four tho'!)