# When is this initialization operation execute? / Variable Initialization

Tags: c

In C, When are these operation '1+1' , '1+2, 'a+1' executed?

```
int x = 1+1;

void foo(int a) {
    const int b = 1 +2;
    const int c = a + 1;
}
```

When the function starts or compiling code?

Thanks.

Comment: If you compile with optimizations, probably never (except for `x`).

Comment: Even a bad compiler should be able to do [*constant folding*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding) with the expression `1 + 2`, and evaluate it at compile-time. The expression `a + 1` can't be evaluated at compile-time, since the value of `a` isn't known.

Comment: Possible dup? https://stackoverflow.com/q/436300/1275169

Comment: Just think about this yourself: when do you know all the values for calculation? Is that during writing the program or executing the program?

Comment: Constant Folding, I did not know that. Thank you very much