# Find value unequal to any value from a given set of distinct values using macro

Tags: c, math, macros, c-preprocessor

Question: how to implement a macro `E` that expands to an integer constant expression such that ...

```
(E != (X) && E != (Y) && E != (Z))
```

... evaluates to 1 for every choice of `X`, `Y`, and `Z` as integer constant expressions with distinct, nonnegative values?

Example:

```
#define X               13
#define Y               45
#define Z               76
#define E               FUNC(X,Y,Z)
#define FUNC(X,Y,Z)     ??

E /* evaluates to any number distinct from all of 13, 45, and 76 */
```

Which formula to use? Any ideas?

Comment: Macro are simply text substitution. The C preprocessor will not perform what you're trying to achieve. Refer to the answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436300/are-constant-c-expressions-evaluated-at-compile-time-or-at-runtime

Comment: Your example doesn't make any sense, you can't paste `FUNC` before defining it, and if you want `E` to be 7, what does that have anything to do with `FUNC`?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts When `E` is expanded `FUNC` is defined. `FUNC(X,Y,Z)` should expand to some constant expression using `X`, `Y`, and `Z`, which evaluates to 7 (for example).

Comment: That's a little quick, @Aziz.  I suspect that you misunderstand the question.  Certainly it's not clear to me that what the OP asks is not possible.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Example: `#define FUNC(X,Y,Z) X+Y+Z+1`. However, this may cause overflow.

Comment: The boost preprocessor library has a set of macros that would achieve this for values less than some fixed limit (by default 256). You should be able to look at the source there to figure out how they did it.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Thanks. It seems that the task is non-trivial for values say `0..INT_MAX`.

Comment: You could also simply return any of `0, 1, 2, 3`, working your way up as you find any matching number. It'd also be useful to see how many numbers lie within that range.

Comment: @Rogue Consider `2, 2548, 459`. How your algorithm will process it? What number it will return?

Comment: @Aziz: Macros are preprocessor token substitution, not text substitution, and include additional operations of concatenation, stringification, and macro replacement.

Comment: @pmor there's a lot of approaches to this. I'd probably keep a bitset (`0000`) and "turn on" any present numbers <4 based on their ordinal value (`set &= (1 << num)`). If the end result is >0, you know some numbers were there, and simply have to find the first 0. In the approach for a macro specifically, you'll probably need a helper function.

Comment: @Aziz The C preprocessor is able to evaluate constant expressions in conditional inclusion. Example: in `#if 1+2` the `1+2` is evaluated according to the rules of constant expressions.

Comment: The proper way to do this compile-time task is to execute a script at compile time that reads the source file and produces the desired result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Given any 3 numbers `X`, `Y` and `Z`, produce an `int` constant that is different from all 3 values.

It seems obvious that either `0`, `1`, `2` or `3` must meet the criteria. So here is a solution:

```
#define FUNC(x,y,z)  (((x) != 0 && (y) != 0 && (z) != 0) ? 0 : \
                      ((x) != 1 && (y) != 1 && (z) != 1) ? 1 : \
                      ((x) != 2 && (y) != 2 && (z) != 2) ? 2 : 3)
```

Here is a more subtle solution evaluating to `0`, `1`, `2` or `3` depending on the last 2 bits of each of the arguments, but evaluating the arguments only once:

```
#define FUNC(x,y,z)  ((int)((0x10201030102010 >>           \
                             (4 * ((1 << ((x) & 3)) |      \
                                   (1 << ((y) & 3)) |      \
                                   (1 << ((z) & 3))))) & 3))
```

Explanation:

- we compose a number between 1 and 14 where each bit is set if one of the arguments has its last 2 bits with this value.
- multiply this value by `4` and shift the magic number `0x10201030102010` by that much and mask by 3 to select a value that is different from all remainders.

A less readable version would multiply by `2` and shift `0x484C484`, using just 32-bit arithmetic:

```
#define FUNC(x,y,z)  ((int)((0x484C484 >> ((2 << ((x) & 3)) | \
                                           (2 << ((y) & 3)) | \
                                           (2 << ((z) & 3)))) & 3))
```

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: no, I really mean `|`: the result of this `a | b | c` expression is a set of 1, 2 or 3 bits, one for each combination of the last 2 bits of `x`, `y` and `z`. The value is in the range `1` to `14` inclusively: `1` if `x`, `y` and `z` are all divisible by 4, `2` if they are all of the form `4*k+1`... `14` if they are `4p+1`, `4q+2` and `4k+3` in whatever order. There are 14 possible sets of 1, 2 or 3 remainders from a set of 4.  For each of these sets, the magic number provides a different remainder, hence a value that is different from `x`, `y` and `z` by construction.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what was expected to see: magic numbers, bitwise operations, combinations of them.

Comment: I see this works well with non-distinct and negative `x,y,z`. The evaluate once property is useful for run time use.

Answer (score 3):

Although not as direct as [@chqrlie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71452956/2410359) first answer, I wanted to add the following finding:

> Only 2 bits of `x, y, z` are needed to generate a distinctive value.

If the least-significant-bit of all 3 `x,y,z` are the same, return `x^1`.

Otherwise `^ 2` with the different `x,y,z`.

```
#define FUNC2BITS(x,y,z) ( \
  (((x)&1 == (y)&1) && ((y)&1 == (z)&1)) ? (x)^1 : \
  (((x)&1 == (y)&1)                    ) ? (z)^2 : \
  (((x)&1 == (z)&1)                    ) ? (y)^2 : (x)^2)

#define FUNC(x,y,z) FUNC2BITS((x)&3, (y)&3, (z)&3)
```

Above does not rely on `x,y,z` being distinct nor restrict them to non-negative. As OP has "with distinct, nonnegative values", can simplify to

```
#define FUNC2BITS(x,y,z) ( \
  (((x)&1 == (y)&1)                    ) ? (z)^2 : \
  (((x)&1 == (z)&1)                    ) ? (y)^2 : (x)^2)
```

Comment: Interesting approach!  Made me think of an alternative without multiple evaluation :)

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking too that bitwise exclusive OR somehow can be used.

Comment: Minor note: GCC/Clang suggests parentheses around comparison in operand of `&`: i.e. `((x)&1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Idea: find current max/min and (if can) add/subtract `1`:

```
#include <limits.h>

#define FUNC(X,Y,Z) \
    MAX(X,MAX(Y,Z)) < INT_MAX ? MAX(X,MAX(Y,Z))+1 : \
    MIN(X,MIN(Y,Z)) > 0       ? MIN(X,MAX(Y,Z))-1 : \
    -1 /* hard case: don't know yet how to implment */

#define MAX(x, y) (((x) > (y)) ? (x) : (y))
#define MIN(x, y) (((x) < (y)) ? (x) : (y))

int x1 = FUNC(23,45,78);      // 79
int x2 = FUNC(0,45,78);       // 79
int x3 = FUNC(23,INT_MAX,78); // 22
int x4 = FUNC(0,1,2);         // 3
int x5 = FUNC(INT_MAX,34,0);  // -1 (hard case)
```

If cannot add/subtract `1` (e.g. `0, 45, INT_MAX`), then "don't know yet".